# Save a text file from a Flutter Android app that can be accessed by user

Tags: android, file, flutter, save

The user of my Android app developed in Flutter should be able to save (export) some data to a text file. The user should be able to find and access this file on his Android device using other apps (including File Managers).

I'm trying:

```
final directory = await getExternalStorageDirectory();
final file = File('${directory.path}/test1.txt');
await file.writeAsString('Test');
```

On an Android 9 phone this saves the file in:

```
/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.mydomain.myapp/files
```

However, I can't access the file (or the directory) using a File Manager app (e.g. Files) on the phone.

(If I connect the phone to a Windows PC using a USB cable, I can access the directory, see the `test1.txt` file, but I can't view or access it.)

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: save it to `/storage/emulated/0/your_app_name/test1.txt` or anywhere thats outside app data.

Comment: @Ryosuke Did you manage to do that in Flutter? For me it only allows to check if files or directories exists but anything else is denied, with the correct permission set.

Comment: @creativecreatorormaybenot now that you mention I remember this happened with me too and then I did it through `MethodChannel`... but I just checked it again before replying to your comment and it worked absolutely fine.

Comment: @Ryosuke what function (from the path_provider plugin or from other place) can you use to get that path ("outside app data")?

Comment: @AlexVang that's the same in almost all android devices.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar use-case except I wanted to save "Downloads" folder in Android. Here's what worked for me:

1. Add Permissions to AndroidManifest.xml

```xml
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.app">

    <!-- Need this permission so that other apps see the saved files -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    ...
```

2. Function for saving your file
   NOTE: that I used [downloads_path_provider](https://pub.dev/packages/downloads_path_provider) instead of "path_provider"

```dart
  static Future<void> save(String filename, String content) async {
    final directory = await DownloadsPathProvider.downloadsDirectory;
    final path = '${directory.path}/$filename';
    final file = File(path);
    Logger().d("Saving $path");
    await file.writeAsString(content);
  }
```

3. Run the App on your phone
4. Enable "Storage" permission for your app
   [image: AppPermissions]
5. Save the file? I was able to view the file saved using a File Browser without being rooted or anything.

Hopefully that works