# How to create and Download a Text file in Flutter Mobile

Tags: flutter, dart, dio

I want to create a text file with some text and download it whenever a user clicks on the "download" button. If the user clicks on the same download button again, it should create a new text file but not re-write or update the existing file since the text will change regularly. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
/// Snippet when user clicks on download second-time 
final permission = Permission.storage;
final status = await permission.status;
debugPrint('>>>Status $status'); /// here it is coming as PermissionStatus.granted
if (status != PermissionStatus.granted) {
  await permission.request();
  if(await permission.status.isGranted){
    directory = Directory('/storage/emulated/0/Download');
    ///perform other stuff to download file
  } else {
   await permission.request();
  }
  debugPrint('>>> ${await permission.status}');
}
directory = Directory('/storage/emulated/0/Download');
```

I made sure storage permissions are being set. Getting this error

FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path = '/storage/emulated/0/Download/codes.txt' (OS Error: Permission denied, errno = 13)

Comment: Here is the solution please check it https://stackoverflow.com/a/59507164/10804348 you need to set different filename every time so that it can't override to previous file

Comment: Thanks @VishalParmar, i've already tried it but it is not working as expected.

Comment: Okay but can you please tell me that what is the issue you are facing by using that code?

Comment: When i call ${path}.writeAsString('text'), sometimes it is not getting downloaded even if respective permissions are set. Also by doing this if user downloads second time it is updating the existing file but not creating new file. @VishalParmar

Comment: Can you show your code here which you have done so far

Comment: @VishalParmar udpated in question

Answer (score 0):

If you don't minding redirection to a browser for download then you can use url_launcher package, [link](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher)

you have to launch your download url and that's it all the download part will be handle by browser.

```
//this is download link (you can use your servers path also, here i am using simple drive link)
const String _url = 'https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1NAEOjqssiQ8f0ATO8kG7At7UDa3sbOg2';

//then to download call this function below 
void _launchURL() async {
  if (!await launch(_url)) throw 'Could not launch $_url';
}
```